# perl XML::LibXML not selector

Tags: css, perl, xpath, selector, xml-libxml

In the following HTML snippet:

`<div><p class="a b c"></p> <p class="a c"></p> <p class="d"></p> </div>`

I want to select only the second `p` element (with the `a` class and without the `b` class) using `not` selector as follows:

`p.a:not(.b)`

The xpath counterpart is

`.//p[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' a ')][not(self::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' b ')])]`.

But when I use that xpath expression, it cannot locate the element.

Is there something else that I can use to achieve the effect of `not` selector?

**Update: It seems I have made a mistake, because `p.a:not(.b)` and its xpath counterpart do seem to work perfectly for `XML::LibXML`.**

**It didn't work because I got one of the `if` condition wrong…**

Answer (score 5):

To get what you want just use this XPath:

```
//p[@class[not(contains(.,"b"))]]
```

In other words : select a p element with a @class attribute that doesn't contain a "b".

EDIT : To be more specific (class has to contain a but not b) :

```
//p[@class[contains(.,"a")] and not(@class[contains(.,"b")])]
```

Comment: Thanks Wiest. I have updated the original post: In my current situation, I have to specify an xpath that contains one class and avoids one class.

Comment: OK. Post is edited. I hope I fully understand this time.

Comment: As it turns out, `p.a:not(.b)` and its xpath counterpart work fine for `XML::LibXML` (I have re-edited the original post again). And I have tried your answer - it works perfectly too. Thanks Wiest.